# Nginx Lua Script for IP Spoofing Prevention Not Working

Tags: nginx, networking, lua, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm working on an Nginx proxy server setup to prevent IP spoofing using a Lua script. Unfortunately, the code doesn't seem to be working correctly, and I'm encountering issues.
i tried using chatgpt for my code but the server won't run/

Here's a snippet of my Nginx configuration (nginx.conf):

```
http {
    lua_shared_dict arp_cache 1000;
    lua_shared_dict dhcp_cache 1000;

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            access_by_lua_file /etc/nginx/ip_spoofing.lua;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;

        location / {
            access_by_lua_file /etc/nginx/ip_spoofing.lua;
        }
    }
}
```

Lua Script (ip_spoofing.lua):

```
local ngx = ngx
local shared_dict = ngx.shared.arp_cache
local shared_dhcp_cache = ngx.shared.dhcp_cache

-- Retrieve sender's IP address and MAC address from headers
local sender_ip = ngx.var.remote_addr
local sender_mac = ngx.req.get_headers()["X-Sender-MAC"]

-- Check if the sender's MAC is stored in the cache
local stored_ip = shared_dict:get(sender_mac)

-- If the sender's MAC is not in the cache, then add it
if not stored_ip then
    shared_dict:set(sender_mac, sender_ip)
end

-- Check if the sender's IP address is in the DHCP cache
if not shared_dhcp_cache:get(sender_ip) then
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "Potential IP spoofing detected for IP ", sender_ip)
    return ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
end

-- If the sender's IP address and MAC address match, then the request is allowed
if stored_ip == sender_ip then
    ngx.log(ngx.INFO, "Request from ", sender_ip, " allowed")
else
    ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "Potential IP spoofing detected for MAC ", sender_mac)
    return ngx.exit(ngx.HTTP_FORBIDDEN)
end
```

The issue seems to be with the Lua script, but I can't pinpoint the exact problem. Can someone please review my configuration and Lua script and help me identify and fix the issue? I expect the script to prevent IP spoofing by checking MAC and IP addresses.

Additional Information:

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.6
I appreciate any insights or solutions you can provide. Thank you!

Comment: Replace `if stored_ip == sender_ip then` with `if not stored_ip or stored_ip == sender_ip then`